# Android, не сериализует список

Tags: android, list, jsoup, serializable

У меня есть список:

```
private volatile List<NewsModel> news_list = new ArrayList<>();
```

В процессе мы его заполняем, а в конце нужно записать:

```
try {
                FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(Constants.FILE_NEWS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
                os.writeObject(news_list);
                os.flush();
                os.close();
                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {}
```

Но почему то он не записывается. Вот класс, объекты которого мы храним в списке:

```
package com.hpk.pr131.hpk_beta.Model;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class NewsModel implements Serializable {
    private String title;
    private String short_Info;
    private String long_Info;
    private String URL;
    private String URL_PHOTO;
    private Bitmap photo;

    public NewsModel() {
        title = "";
        short_Info = "";
        long_Info = "";
        URL = "";
        URL_PHOTO = "";
        photo = null;
    }

    public void setLong_Info(String long_Info) {
        this.long_Info = long_Info;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setShort_Info(String short_Info) {
        this.short_Info = short_Info;
    }

    public void setURL(String URL) {
        this.URL = URL;
    }
    public void setURL_PHOTO(String URL) {
        this.URL_PHOTO = URL;
    }

    public void setPhoto(Bitmap photo) {
        this.photo = photo;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getShort_Info() {
        return short_Info;
    }

    public String getLong_Info() {
        return long_Info;
    }

    public String getURL() {
        return URL;
    }

    public Bitmap getPhoto() {
        return photo;
    }

    public String getURL_PHOTO() {
        return URL_PHOTO;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "LongINfo: "+long_Info;
    }
}
```

В чем может быть проблема ?

Comment: Не звписывается - в смысле файл не создается? По какому пути? Может разрешений нет?

Comment: @metalurgus Скорее всего выдает ошибку. Так как пробовал логировать после каждой строчке, то после "os.writeObject(news_list);" логи не выводит. Но и ошибку не возвращает. Просто напросто не записывает в файл

Comment: Ну, так добавьте в `catch` `e.printStackTrace()`

Comment: Спасибо, что подсказали это, ошибка в том, что не сериализуется Bitmap в объекте.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно в AndroidManifest.xml нет прав на запись файлов, добавьте строку

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```